# update-mgpolicyhomerealmdiscoverypolicy ... how to specify an object for the appliesto parameter

Tags: powershell, graph, azure-active-directory

The syntax for the command specifies that the applies to parameter should be this:

```
 <IMicrosoftGraphDirectoryObject[]>
```

When I try this command, I get an entity set mismatch error. Any idea what needs to be supplied for this command?

The directory object in question is a registered app:

```
[@odata.type, #microsoft.graph.servicePrincipal]

$directoryobject=Get-MgDirectoryObject -DirectoryObjectId 5cacc587-24f4-43a4-9aae-6d59927e7bf9

Update-MgPolicyHomeRealmDiscoveryPolicy -HomeRealmDiscoveryPolicyId 0b4f3006-d531-46db-a239-115752fa41c7 -AppliesTo $directoryobject
```

Update-MgPolicyHomeRealmDiscoveryPolicy_UpdateExpanded:

```
 The context URI 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects/$entity' references the entity set with name 'directoryObjects'; however, the name of the expected entity set is 'directoryObjects.appliesTo' and does not match the entity set referenced in the context URI.
```

I've tried every syntax I can think of, but this is the closest to a meaningful error that I've gotten.

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 0):

The error might be related to the input passing to [`-AppliesTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/update-mgpolicyhomerealmdiscoverypolicy?view=graph-powershell-1.0#-appliesto) parameter in `Update-MgPolicyHomeRealmDiscoveryPolicy` command. Try below workaround to make it work as expected.

Instead of passing `directoryObject` as a string, create an array with single element `directoryObject` to handle input accurately.

```
$directoryobject=Get-MgDirectoryObject -DirectoryObjectId xxxxxx
$directoryArray = @($directoryObject)
Update-MgPolicyHomeRealmDiscoveryPolicy -HomeRealmDiscoveryPolicyId 0b4f3006-d531-46db-a239-115752fa41c7 -AppliesTo $directoryArray
```

Make sure that you have installed graph directory objects module without any issues.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObjects 
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObjects 
Connect-Mggraph
```

[image]